# Can't access a updated Bootstrap Dropdown with AJAX jQuery using Flask

Tags: python, jquery, ajax, flask, bootstrap-4

i am new to jQuery and Flask and i try to update my Dropdown Menu with a AJAX request.

My dropdown is like this:

```
            <div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons">
                    <div class="dropdown">
                        <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle"  id="b_btncontrollers" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                            Regler
                        </button>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu" id="c_btncontrollers" name="btncontrollers" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
                            {% for control in controllers %}
                            <a class="dropdown-item" name="controllers" id={{ control }} value={{ control }} href="#"> {{ control }} </a>
                            {% endfor %}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

I transfer a list from my Python programm, to generate a dropdown, presenting the single elements of the list. 
This works well, but if i try to update the dropdown, i can't access the new items of the list. 
In my AJAX request i doing this:

```
                $.ajax({
                method: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json",
                url: "/updateNavBar",
                data: JSON.stringify($(this).attr("value"))
            }).done(function (data) {


                for (var control in data['controllers']) {
                    $("#btncontrollers").append('<a class="dropdown-item" name="controllers" value=' + data['controllers'][control] + ' id=' + data['controllers'][control] + ' href = "#" > ' + data['controllers'][control] + ' </a > ');

                }
```

This works fine as well. In my Dom Explorer the new elements are existing.
To display the selected item i use a script like this:

```
        $(function () {
        $("#c_btncontrollers a").click(function () {
            console.log("Sollte aktualisieren")
            $("#b_btncontrollers:first-child").text($(this).text());
            $("#b_btncontrollers:first-child").val($(this).text());
        });
    });
```

Without updating all works well, but if i put new items to the dropdown i can't access this new items.
I don't know where is the problem. Maybe someone of you knows where the problem is.
I am using Python version 3.7, Bootstrap v4.3.1 and jQuery version 3.4.1

Edit:

The new items a shown in the dropdown but i can't select them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue with the click handler not working is because you creating those handlers on specific elements with the selector in your click handler:

```
$("#c_btncontrollers a").click(function () {...}
```

But jQuery gives you ways to look for clicks on any items with a selector, whether they exist when you set up the handler or not.   Basically, you add a click handler to the entire document, and then look at the click target to see if it is the right thing.

jQuery has done this in a couple different ways over the years, but since you're using **jQuery 1.7 or higher**, it works like this:

```
$(function () {
  $(document).on("click", "#c_btncontrollers a", function() {
    console.log("Sollte aktualisieren")
    $("#b_btncontrollers:first-child").text($(this).text());
    $("#b_btncontrollers:first-child").val($(this).text());
  });
});
```

An older way of doing it might also still work:

```
$(function () {
  $("#c_btncontrollers a").live("click", function() {
    console.log("Sollte aktualisieren")
    $("#b_btncontrollers:first-child").text($(this).text());
    $("#b_btncontrollers:first-child").val($(this).text());
  });
});
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Ohh! Great! Thanks men! I tried it and it works! Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue might just be in your append statement.  You're missing some quotes.  Try this:

```
$("#btncontrollers").append('<a class="dropdown-item" name="controllers" value="' + data['controllers'][control] + '" id="' + data['controllers'][control] + '" href = "#" > ' + data['controllers'][control] + ' </a > ');
```

All I did was add double quotes around the `value` and `id` attributes.   Dynamically adding dropdown items should not be a problem.

Comment: No, this dont change it. In the Dom Explorer the appended a tag is displayed in the right way. But the Problem is, i can't use this item with js. I think it's because the item is added after the Dom is loaded. But thanks for your help

Comment: Sorry, now I understand your question more.   You're saying that the click handler isn't working with the new ones.   I will write you another answer.  :-)